# Serving ionic vue build through perl server is not working

Tags: vue.js, perl, ionic-framework, catalyst

I have a perl application and want to change parts of it to an ionic app.

I'm building my ionic vue app with `ionic build` and redirect in a perl controller to the index.html file in the generated dist directory.

There is no error or anything, but the content of the page is empty. There are html elements missing:
[image]

normally inside the ion-router-outlet there are elements like ion-page and so on.

I'm starting a server with a script that calls this

```
use Catalyst::ScriptRunner;
Catalyst::ScriptRunner->run('My::PWA::Demo', 'Server');
```

When I serve the dist folder with `serve -s dist` (installed with `npm install -g serve`) all works as expected. There are also a few more javascript files loaded.

Does anyone has an idea what the reason could be that the page is shown correctly when serving it with "serve" but not through the perl server?

edit: I did the same thing with a vue only app and everything works there, so maybe only the ionic part is a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the hash mode for the vue router (https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-mode) it works, but I still don't know how to make it work in html5-mode